# Conditionally formatting rows when their ColumnA cell starts 'sunday'

Tags: formatting, google-sheets

I would like to add custom conditional formatting in Google Spreadsheets such that when the cell in ColumnA starts with `Κυριακή` then the whole row will be formatted.

Comment: only in the A column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format, Conditional formatting..., Select your range width, eg `A:Z`, Format cells if..., Custom formula is:

```
=left($a1,7)="Κυριακή"
```

choose your Formatting style, <kbd>Done</kbd>.